# ClearCase View Profile: Can not determine if the view is associated

Tags: java, jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-plugins

I am currently writing a Jenkins plugin, where I have a button that starts a build. 
In the Java code that is executed when the user clicks the button, there are some cleartool commands. 
First, it creates a view:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cleartool mkview -tag " + viewTag + " " + viewPath);
```

Then there is a call to a method that creates the config spec file and writes the correct content to it:

```
createFile();
```

After that it updates the config spec:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cleartool setcs -tag " + viewTag + " " + path");
```

And at the and of the method it starts the build:

```
Hudson.getInstance().getQueue().schedule(project, 0, new CauseAction(new Cause.UserIdCause()));
```

First, there was the problem that the config spec wasn't set correctly, it was always missing several lines. I inserted `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the code in order to wait for the createFile-method to finish writing the file. Now the config spec seems to be set correctly, so I assume that this issue is done. 
However, I now have another problem:
When I go to the ClearCase Explorer, look at the properties of my view and select the tab 'Profile', I get the following error message:

*Can not determine if the view is associated.

The config spec for the 'myViewTag' view has been modified outside of the ClearCase View Profile tools, and can no longer be interpreted by the tools.

Would you like to attempt an automatic recovery of the config spec?*

Is there anything I can do to handle or avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

If the [`setcs`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm) command is applied to a snapshot view, it triggers an update which can be lengthy.

If the set config spec was aborted once and then resumed, it can lead to that error message.

You need to launch manually from the ClearCase Explorer a full update of the view, then try again your script through Jenkins to see if the error persists.

In your case though, you seem to create a dynamic view: try and delete that view, before launching your Jenkins job again (which will re-create it).

As mention in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013760382), make sure that the [view storage path](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_find_view_storage.htm) (the one ending in `.vws`) is correct.

Comment: 1) Checked the vws path, it's ok 2) Added `Thread.sleep(60000)` after every step to make sure that all creating and updating has time to finish - didn't help. Do you think that it takes even longer? 3) Added a quiet period in `Hudson.getInstance().getQueue().schedule(project, 100, new CauseAction(new Cause.UserIdCause()));` - didn't help 4) The manual view update is only an option if is a snapshot view, right? At least for me it is shown greyed in the CC Explorer 5) I deleted and recreated many views many times - it's always the same. 6) Can't I set the view profile or something like that?

Comment: @JenkinsUser update is only for snapshot views, and you are creating dynamic ones. What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: The version is 8.0.0.10

Comment: @JenkinsUser so a ClearTeam version. I thought it had no longer access to cleartool, only rcleartoo.

Comment: Okay.. never heard of it ;) But rcleartool commands (e.g. `rcleartool help`) don't work, whereas cleartool commands do.

Comment: You don't happen to have another idea..?

Comment: @JenkinsUser no, I would try working with dynamic views though (same setcs, but no update step)